# Making a web-crawler to have loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-crawler, axios, cheerio

I tried to make my web-crawler to have a loop to crawl the webpage from 1 to around 500. But the result does not include any directed one but to return an only void array.

This code is based on cheerio, jQuery, and axios. JavaScript.

```
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const log = console.log;

const getHtml = async() => {
    var i=0
    while (i<493){
        try {
            return await axios.get("https://playentry.org/ds#!/qna?sort=created&rows=20&page="+i);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
};

getHtml()
    .then(html => {
        let ulList = [];
        const $ = cheerio.load(html.data);
        const $bodyList = $("div.discussContentWrapper div.discussListWrapper table.discussList").children("tr.discussRow");

        $bodyList.each(function(i, elem){
            ulList[i] = {
                title:$(this).find('td.discussTitle div.discussTitleWrapper'),
                writer:$(this).find('td.discussTitle td.discussViewCount'),
                viewcount:$(this).find('td.discussTitle td.discussViewCount'),
                likecount:$(this).find('td.discussTitle div.discussLikeCount'),
                date:$(this).find('td.discussTitle td.discussDate'),
            };
        });

    const data = ulList.filter(n => n.title);
    return data;
})
.then(res => log(res));
```

The output is `'''[]'''` or `'''[ [] ]'''` with no real outputs.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: That page uses javascript to load elements. You would need puppeteer or similar.

Comment: 1. You have to use node.js to make this request cross domain.
2. The website is a angular app which is client side javascript rendering. To capture these data, you need puppeteer. That will render angular and you can select the rendered elements you need.